# How to use .NET WebClient calls in Clojure-CLR 1.4.1

Tags: clojure, clojureclr

In the question: [Idiomatic way to write .NET interop function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622549/idiomatic-way-to-write-net-interop-function) I found the following code segment:

```
(import '(System.Net HttpWebRequest NetworkCredential)
        '(System.IO StreamReader))
```

When I start a REPL and enter:

> (import '(System.IO StreamReader))

all is OK.  But when I enter:

> (import '(System.Net HttpWebRequest))

(I don't need the NetworkCredential functionality) I get:

```
My.ns=> (import '(System.Net HttpWebRequest))
Bad type
NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  cl
ojure.lang.Util.NameForType (D:\work\clojure-clr-1.4.1-fix\Clojure\Clojure\Lib\U
til.cs:729)
```

Oh, and I have previously done:

```
My.ns=> (System.Reflection.Assembly/LoadWithPartialName "System.Net")
#<RuntimeAssembly System.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b
03f5f7f11d50a3a>
```

So what else do I need to do?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you try `(import 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in 1.4.  It comes from not properly handling a type being accessible from more than one assembly.  In this case, `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` is in the `System` assembly.  Importing that class before you load the `System.Net` assembly works just fine.  After you load the `System.Net` assembly, `HttpWebRequest` is accessible from two assemblies (thanks to a `TypeForwardedTo` attribute in `System.Net`).  In ClojureCLR 1.4.1, this is not handled properly.

Solutions:

1. Either don't load `System.Net` or do your import of `HttpWebRequest`
   prior to doing so.
2. Download the latest version of ClojureCLR -- the
   bug is fixed.
3. If you need to stay with 1.4.1 and can build it
   yourself, it's a one-line fix.  Look at
   https://github.com/clojure/clojure-clr/commit/38c34c2a60a63d5933386e412a250c5e8b879d5b
   .